# Which measure to use to classify some distributions

Tags: classification

I have a lot of data sets corresponding to particular events, each event is a collection of some $N$ real values between 0 and 1. Some of these events don't interest me, and I want to filter them out. To this end I want to associate with each event a value that would let me order events from the most useful to least useful and institute an arbitrary cutoff.

**Let's consider some histograms:**

This is an example of a good event, that I definitely want to keep.
[image: The good]

This is an example of a bad event, that I want to potentially filter out.
[image: The bad]

This is an example of an obviously bad event, that I definitely want to filter out.
[image: The ugly]

What kind of measure should I use to classify these events? I've tried stabbing in the dark with kurtosis (gives best results), skewness, means and central moments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you would be better off looking at plots of the cumulative distribution than histograms.  That way you can more clearly compare them, because you will be able see that for each event $p$ proportion of values are less than $c$.  As they will be line plots, you could also plot several at once, using colour to distinguish between events (something you can't do easily with histograms; and if you tried another technique eg with faceting, you should change so the vertical axis is the density rather than the count, so you have more comparable scales across events).

Then you may have a straightforward job of just setting choosing some values to distinguish between good and bad.

By which I mean - you don't say what the real difference is between good and bad but it looks potentially straightforward. If more than 50% of values are greater than 0.02, perhaps that is a "bad" event (this is just a guess from eyeballing your histograms).

Comment: I tried it ever which way, maybe I need to remove a layer of indirection and post that question instead. .)